# Getting a union query to create single records

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

So I've put together a union query in access, but it displays in this fashion.

```
Name      Column1       Column2
John         1             0
Jim          2             0
Mike         3             0
John         0             2
Jim          0             1
Mike         0             3
```

I would like for it to display like this:

```
Name      Column1       Column2
John        1             2
Jim         2             1
Mike        3             3
```

In my select statement I'm setting column2 to 0 in the first portion of the union statement, and setting column1 to 0 in the second part. Now I realize that's why I'm getting the 0s in the end result, but is there a way to achieve my desired display with a union or do I need something more complex.

EDIT: The reason I set those columns to 0, was to avoid it asking me to enter a value when it could not find a value for column1 or 2.

PS. this is not my actual query, but rather just a quick example I was able to throw on here for question purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [Name], max([Column1]) as col1, max([Column2]) as col2
from ( put union query here ) as x
group by [Name]
```

edit -- didn't notice that your data was a query result and not a table. Put your current query where indicated in the from clause (as an inline view)